# Sorting through 3 tables MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, computer-science

Hello I am trying to sort through these 3 [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbQdi.jpg)

I need to create a query that goes through the 'Author' Table,

grabs the author num

Then goes to the 'Wrote' table to find the 'BookCode' from the AuthorNum of the last table

Then to finally go through the Book table to list the title of the book and the first name and last name of the author.

I was thinking of using a join table but am not too solid on my uinderstanding on how it works. Nested select statements was my next guess but I can't get them to go through so many tables.

If anyone could help me that would be fantastic, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the table information as text, not images. And you're correct to use `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `INNER JOINS` to match up the data

```
SELECT *
FROM authors AS a
INNER JOIN wrote AS w
  ON a.AuthorNum = w.AuthorNum
INNER JOIN book AS b
  ON w.BookCode = b.BookCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this :
(I named the first table name to first)
    Select a.`Title` as title, w.`AuthorFirst` as firstName, w.`AuthorLast` as lastName
    From wrote as w
    Inner Join author as a
    Inner Join first as f
    On (Select ww.`AuthorNum` From WroteTable as ww Order By DESC LIMIT 1) = f.`AuthorNum`
    On f.`BookCode` = a.`BookCode`